# Check if data exists using firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How can I check if the `days` node exists using Firebase Cloud Function?

Pseudo-code inside `index.js`:

```
if(days.exists())
{
    //do something
}
```

[image: see data structure here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// outside of function body
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// inside function body
return admin.database().ref('days').once('value').then(snap => {
  if (snap.exists()) {
    // do something
  }
});
```